# Dynamically jumping around Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

With the addition of a "quick access" home screen to our app, the user is now supposed to be able to jump into various sections of the storyboard to perform the desired operation.

For example:
Normally, to get to the camera VC to take a picture, the path of segues flow through several other VC/TBC views.

The *Home Screen* essentially allows a shortcut to that camera VC for more immediate access.

BUT... upon backing out of the camera VC, it would still be preferable to place the user into the contained segue flow once again and allow them to segue back or divert into other areas of the Storyboard.

[image]

Is this possible with Storyboards?
How can I still load each VC as if the user segued to the camera VC normally?

Comment: Why? If you go somewhere directly via a menu I expect to go back to the menu (or to have to use the menu to go elsewhere)

Comment: You have a point (which I'm aware of).  But our data structure flow is similar to that of files and folders.  Which is then helpful for the user once they back out of the camera VC to be informed what specific "folder" and area of the app they are in.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik i think the only way to do this is to instantiate every VC you have in storyboard add it to navigation controller, then display your desired one, and get back by popViewController..but I think this would take very looong time, I don't think this is best approach